# Add `activate.sh` and `deactivate.sh` to Conda Environment Created From YAML FIle

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, mamba

I want to include `activate.sh` and `deactivate.sh` scripts in a Conda environment that is created for users when they do `conda env create -f environment.yaml`. Is there a way to have these scripts automatically copied into the `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda` directory when it's created? Or do I need to write a script that creates the environment, and then copies the files manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Package reusable activation scripts

The Conda way to do this would be to bundle these files in a package (yes, a script-only package), ship it to a user channel on Anaconda Cloud, then have the package be installed as part of the YAML.

#### Example (and template)

Here's an example package I use: [`envvar-pythonusersite-true`](https://github.com/mfansler/envvar-pythonnousersite-true). Its only purpose is to set the `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` environment variable to `true` when the environment activates. The GitHub repository is a template, so simple to copy and I have some basic directions on what needs to be adjusted to ship it to a different Anaconda Cloud user channel.

The actual package is [on my user site](https://anaconda.org/merv/envvar-pythonnousersite-true) and can be used in a YAML like:

```yaml
# omitting other stuff
dependencies:
  - merv::envvar-pythonnousersite-true
```

If the script package is the only one from my channel, then I will use this explicit channel syntax (`<channel>::`), rather than add my channel to the `channels:` list.

Note that this example could technically have been a `noarch: generic` package, since it only delivers scripts. The `.bat` files will only run on Windows and the `.sh` could be edited to check handle Linux/macOS differences (though for environment variables, that isn't necessary).