# conda env variables assignment and location

Tags: environment-variables, conda

We can use

```bash
conda env config vars set MY_VAR=something
```

or in an `environment.yml` block

```yaml
variables:
  MY_VAR: something
  MY_VAR2: ${CONDA_PREFIX}/abc
```

to define variables for the conda environment.

The set variables become available when we do `conda activate <env>` and are unset on `con deactivate`.

See e.g.

- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables
- [How to set specific environment variables when activating conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598963/how-to-set-specific-environment-variables-when-activating-conda-environment)

I would expect the definitions to be in

```bash
<env location>/etc/conda/[de]activate.d
```

but the are not, even though after `conda activate <env>` they are shown when I do

```bash
conda env config vars list
```

This gives something like

```
MY_VAR = something
MY_VAR2 = ${CONDA_PREFIX}/abc
```

With `$CONDA_PREFIX` not being expanded.
When I do

```bash
conda env config vars set MY_VAR2=${CONDA_PREFIX}/abc
conda deactivate 
conda activate <env>
```

it works as expected and `$CONDA_PREFIX` is expanded.

So,

- Where are the variables defined, i.e. set / unset?
- Why is `$CONDA_PREFIX` not expanded when used in the `environment.yml`?
- How to set variables using environment variables via `environment.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

The `conda env` environment variables use a separate mechanism. It stores variables in a `conda-meta/state` file. So, for example:

```bash
$ conda create -n foo
$ conda activate foo
(foo) $ conda env config vars set MY_VAR=something
(foo) $ cat $CONDA_PREFIX/conda-meta/state
# {"env_vars": {"MY_VAR": "something"}}
```

This is a crude mechanism that does not support dynamic variables (i.e., using `$CONDA_PREFIX`). Your example at the CLI, is expanded by the shell *prior* to it being passed as an argument to Conda. Whereas Conda never passes the YAML through a shell expansion, so it directly copies the literal text to the `conda-meta/state` file.

If you require dynamic variables, then use activation scripts. The current Conda idiom for delivering reusable activation scripts in an environment is via a Conda package. Some details in [Add `activate.sh` and `deactivate.sh` to Conda Environment Created From YAML FIle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76788820/570918).

Comment: Thanks. Ok, thats a pity. Any idea if there are plans to change this behavior and have both ways create an [de]activation script, with proper shell expansion? A quick search on existing , open issues did not help.